# Qt, do not freeze GUI input element when slow operation

Tags: c++, qt

I have QLineEdit as search input.

When value of search input changed it call slot:

```
void
myWidget::slotApplyItemsFilter(const QString &searchString)
{
    viewArea.applyItemsFilter(searchString.trimmed());
}
```

Here implementation of applyItemsFilter method:

```
void
myViewArea::applyItemsFilter(const QString &searchString)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rowCount(QModelIndex()); i += 1) {
        setRowHidden(
            i,
            searchString.isEmpty()
                ? false
                : !model.isMatched(i, searchString)
        );
    }
}
```

Here implementation of isMatched method of model:

```
bool
myModel::isMatched(
    const int      row,
    const QString &searchString
) const
{
    return (
        (0 > row && items.size() <= row)
            ? false
            : items.at(row).name.contains(searchString, Qt::CaseInsensitive)
    );
}
```

It all works fine. But when view/model contains many items (e.g. 1000) it working slow and freeze QLineEdit (can't type symbols, no, I can, but it looks like freezed queue) while it not calculate for each item.

UPD: Yes, I try set Qt::QueuedConnection for slot, it not help.

How I can make unfreezed search input?

Comment: Maybe you can remove the model from the view temporarily. Then after the loop, add it again. Sometimes it's the repeated signals emissions to the view that cause slowdowns. But since set rows visible is a view property, I am unsure whether that works. Alternatively, you can explicitly install a proxy model to implement the visibility feature.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb it not help for "unfreeze" search input, because now it always work directly: input.changed->widget.slotApply->view.apply->model.isMatched. I ask how to unfreeze input. Not important how many time works model and view. Just unfreeze input only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "unfreeze" the input widget only. The input is frozen because you don't return control to the event loop for a long time, thus the entire GUI is frozen.

The queued connection won't help, since you run all the code in one batch.

A basic improvement would be to disable the view widget updates while the row visibility is being changed.

The simplest approach is to use a filtering proxy model.

```
class myViewArea : .... {
  QSortFilterProxyModel viewModel;
  ...
};

myViewArea::myViewArea(...) {
  ...
  viewModel.setSourceModel(&model);
  viewModel.setFilterKeyColumn(...); // the column holding the name
  viewModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(false);
  setModel(&viewModel);
}

void myViewArea::applyItemsFilter_viewModel(const QString &needle) {
  // allows all when needle is empty
  NoUpdates noUpdates(this);
  viewModel.setFilterFixedString(needle);
}

class NoUpdates {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(NoUpdates)
  QWidget *const w;
  bool const prev = w->updatesEnabled();
public:
  NoUpdates(QWidget *w) : w(w) { w->setUpdatesEnabled(false); }
  ~NoUpdates() { w->setUpdatesEnabled(prev); }
};
```

Alternatively, you need to make the code not block the event loop for very long. One  way is to run the search cooperatively with the main thread. The indices are best iterated in the direction that minimizes the repaint cost, i.e. always starting at the section of the model, delineated by the row worked on, that has the most items.

```
void myViewArea::applyItemsFilter_gui(const QString &needle)
{
  bool inFirstHalf = rowAt(0) <= model.rowCount()/2;
  // iterate backwards in the first half of the rows
  int dir = inFirstHalf ? -1 : +1;
  int i = dir > 0 ? model.rowCount()-1 : 0;
  auto isValidRow = [this, dir](int i){
    return (dir > 0 && i < model.rowCount()) || i >= 0;
  };

  runCooperatively(this, [this, needle, isValidRow, i, dir, 
                          n = NoUpdates(this)]() mutable
  {
    if isValidRow (i) do {
      setRowVisible(i, needle.isEmpty() || model.isMatched(i, needle), this);
      i += dir;
    } while isRowInViewport(i); // update all visible rows in one go
    return isValidRow(i);
  });
}

bool myViewArea::isRowInViewport(int row) const {
  auto first = indexAt(viewport()->rect().topLeft());
  auto last = indexAt(viewport()->rect().bottomRight());
  return row >= 0 && row < model.rowCount() 
         && row >= first.row() && (!last.isValid() || row <= last.row());
}
```

Yet another approach is to run the code that doesn't need to be on the main thread concurrently. Names are collected in a list object, and passed to concurrent code that computes the visibility. Once the visibility is computed, the row visibility is set cooperatively in the main thread.

```
void myViewArea::applyItemsFilter_concurrent(const QString &needle)
{
  auto visible = QtConcurrent::mapped(getNames(), 
    [needle](const QString &name){ return isMatched(needle, name); });
  runCooperativelyAfter(this, future, [this, visible, i = 0,
    n = NoUpdates(this)]() mutable
  {
    if (i >= rowCount() || i >= visible.resultCount()) return false;
    setRowVisible(i, visible.resultAt[i], this);
    return ++i;
  });
}
```

The two preceding approaches are fairly similar in the appearance of code, and are written in continuation-passing style. It'd be much nicer with coroutines, of course - that's a TODO.

Running the code cooperatively in the most general fashion can be done as follows:

```
/// Runs a functor cooperatively with the event loop in the context object's
/// thread, as long as the functor returns true. The functor will run at least
/// once, unless the context object gets destroyed before control returns to
/// event loop.
template <class Fun>
static void runCooperatively(QObject *context, Fun &&fun) {
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(context, [context, f = std::forward<Fun>(fun)]{
    auto *hook = new QTimer(context);
    QObject::connect(hook, &QTimer::timeout, [hook, fun = std::forward<Fun>(f)]{
      if (!fun()) hook->deleteLater();
    });
    hook->start();
  });
}

/// Runs a functor cooperatively after a future is completed
template <class Fun, typename Res>
static void runCooperativelyAfter(QObject *ctx, const QFuture<Res> &future, Fun &&fun) {
  auto *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<Res>(ctx);
  watcher->setFuture(future);
  QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher::finished, 
    [future, ctx, f = std::forward<Fun>(fun) {
      future->deleteLater();
      runCooperatively(ctx, [fun = std::forward<Fun>(f)]{ fun(); });
    }
  );
}
```

Other shared functions follow:

```
// Note: an empty needle would match per QString search semantics,
// but it's unexpected - better to make it explicit so that
// a maintainer doesn't have to dig in the documentation.
// ***Static Method***
bool myModel::isMatched(const QString &needle, const QString &name)
{
  assert(!needle.isEmpty());
  return name.contains(needle, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
}

bool myModel::isMatched(const int row, const QString &needle) const
{
  return row >= 0 && row < items.size() &&
         isMatched(needle, items.at(row).name);
}

QStringList myModel::getNames() const
{
  // The below should be fast enough, but let's time it to make sure
  return time([this]{
    QStringList names;
    names.reserve(items.size());
    for (auto &item : items) names.push_back(item.name);
    return names;
  });
}

template <class C> static void setRowVisible(int row, bool vis, C *obj) {
  obj->setRowHidden(row, !vis);
}

template <class Fun> 
static typename std::result_of<Fun()>::type time(const Fun &code) {
  struct Timing {
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    Timing () { timer.start(); }
    ~Timing () { qDebug() << timer.elapsed(); }
  } timing;
  return code();
}
```

Your original code has lots of doubly-inverted logic that made it hard to comprehend what's going on. Yes, the discovery of the ternary operator can make one giddy, I understand that :) Yet this complication is gratuitous, as C++ has short circuit evaluation, and the ternary operator gymnastics are unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it one thread and one event loop. With timer works better, but input periodically freezed (when view redraw). I think maybe make copy of items and move it to separated thread, and send signal (boolean visibility flags for all items) once to view when known states of all items.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Global explanation! Now I use proxy model with timer.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to manually invoke the event loop while doing long processing operations. This can be accomplished by using [QCoreApplication::processEvents(..)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) in your search loop, but only every so often, otherwise you end up wasting more clock cycles.

```
void
myViewArea::applyItemsFilter(const QString &searchString)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rowCount(QModelIndex()); i += 1) {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();    // <<< Let other things happen
        setRowHidden(
            i,
            searchString.isEmpty()
                ? false
                : !model.isMatched(i, searchString)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault

Comment: This can be tricky, it is possible to end up with event loop calling some methods (event handlers or slots) again re-entrantly when you call processEvents, and usually methods aren't designed to be re-entrant. Or changing something else, like in this case, if model rows get removed in processEvents, i could be beyond last row when it is used.